# How do I add a profile picture on SE using a mobile phone?

Tags: support, mobile-web, profile-picture

I have tried a lot to change my profile picture on this site by using my mobile phone, but couldn't find any options. My laptop is being repaired, so I can't use it. How can I change my profile picture by using a mobile phone?

Comment: Are you using your mobile browser, or the app? The app is no longer supported.

Comment: @F1Krazy I am using my mobile browser.

Answer (score 7):

The [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) version of the site doesn't offer the option to edit your profile. The full site does; you can scroll down to the footer and tap the 'full site' link to switch to the (partially) responsive site, which does allow the option to edit your profile (including uploading a new profile picture).

[image]