# Make navigating to the full site easier on mobile profile page

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, mobile-web, profile-picture

I recently tried to change my profile picture on my phone, but encountered a problem, which was that I could not add a new picture. All it said was to go to the "full site", which I had no idea how to get to because I generally always use my computer.

Later, while reading through on my computer, I found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349383/how-do-i-add-a-profile-picture-on-se-using-a-mobile-phone), in which a helpful user answered the question, which turned out that it was a ***tiny* bit of text** at the very bottom of the web page that when tapped, will take a user to the "full site".

For a new user, the chances are, they **wouldn't find** that tiny part at the bottom. So to help new users and make them more comfortable with the site on mobile, I thought that it'd be a great idea to change the text that says "on our full site" to "on our full site, here" where the "here" is that [webpage-link-blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink), to be obvious, so that the new user **can just tap it and go straight to the "full site"**. It doesn't have to be with the whole "here" thing, it could be perhaps button or a different word. The part that matters is that right now, it can be *quite confusing* to new users on mobile.

Comment: Honestly, it would be really nice to not have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page every time regardless, not just in the profile picture case. Maybe like a dismissible banner under the menu bar or something.

Comment: Good idea. We need something to help the user know where to go.

Comment: It would be really nice if there was never a need to.