# What does 'Note: you can use the full site to upload a new picture' mean?

Tags: bug, profile-page, mobile-web, profile-picture

I wanted to change my profile photo, but unfortunately when I click on change picture, that's what I get:

[image: error message when trying to change profile picture]

It says:

> Note: you can use the full site to upload a new picture

And I can't seem to be able to upload a new picture. What should I do to change my profile picture?

Comment: Go to the footer, and click on "full site".

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364653/make-navigating-to-the-full-site-easier-on-mobile-profile-page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's some odd remnant of the now deprecated mobile web, which doesn't support uploading new picture.

You should be able to choose "Request desktop site" in your mobile browser settings, then you should see this when editing the picture:

[image: upload new picture button available]